# Can i create Web App to be used on smart-phones without internet ? How?

Tags: java, javascript, iphone, android, blackberry

I want to make cross - platform app which could be used for different smart-phones, and been advised to make 'Web App'.

Can 'web app' work without internet?
How to do it, which programing language to use?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean Internet is normally available but it should continue to work while there is no data connection?

Comment: no i mean where internet is normally not available

Answer (score 4):

Oh sure. Bundle all your HTML, JS anc CSS with your app, and have a thin Java/Android app over these assets. If you are not making any calls to fetch or show external HTML/pages, you don't need internet.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely no.

While it is possible to run "[web apps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Apps)" without access to the internet (you can simply execute Javascript locally from some browsers), it would be

- (Subjectively) not particularly useful.
- Not supported by many devices, whom (like the iPhone) do not allow the storage and execution of arbitrary, non-native code on the device.

However, some frameworks do exist that hold the idea of "web apps" can be a distribution model. For example, [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) allows you to code in HTML5/Javascript, and distribute your app to multiple platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can work offline once downloaded from web. Use just any regular programming language for web application development. If you are good at programming, I recommend ruby-on-rails or ASP.NET MVC with Jquery mobile.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into frameworks like:

- PhoneGap: http://www.phonegap.com/
- jQuery Mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/
- GWT Mobile: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/

Your question is very broad so it's hard to give a useful answer. Essentially when making a web app you'll normally be working with javascript, css, and html... though there are frameworks which will let you write your app in Java/Python/Ruby and then have those languages create your app for you. Keep in mind this is mostly all front facing stuff though. The actual web app will still need to have a backend written in a programming language that you understand (hopefully).

Good luck :).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the jQuery Mobile API - I started using it recently and it has proved to be a viable option. Check [this](http://jquerymobile.com/) out.

Comment: Ah but the problem would be if you wanted it to work on ALL (or mostly all) platforms, it would have to have internet

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_Application_Cache  with an application cache your Web App can be used offline. It will cache the resources you specify to disk.

So you can write a Javascript + HTML webpage/app and use it both on and off line.

You can cache/store:

- HTML
- CSS
- Javascript
- Images
- GET Requests